# LongListMultiselector with checkbox not for all the items

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need a list where for some items, there should be a checkbox available and user should be able to check multiple checkboxes i.e select multiple items.
So I made use of toolkit: "LongListMultiselector".

But I cannot figure out a way to hide the checkboxes for some element? Is there actually a way while using "LongListMultiselector" or should I change the control element.

Comment: You mean, you wanted to hide the check boxes for some items within the `LonglistMultiSelector`?

Comment: @Kulasangar : Yes exactly!!